# Bluemix SQL Databaseの接続情報取得について

Tags: bluemix

BluemixのSQL Databaseサービスのみを利用しようとしています。
サービスをインスタンスにバインドすると環境変数に接続情報がセットされますが、インスタンスは作らずに、直接サービスのみを利用することはできますか？どのように接続情報を知ることができるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

SQL DatabaseはBluemix上で稼動するアプリケーションからだけでなく、外部から接続することもできます。ただし、接続に必要な情報を得るには一旦インスタンスにバインドして、環境変数VCAP_SERVICESの値を確認するしかないようです。(Free beta, smallプランで確認しました)

同じDB2のDBaaSであるdashDBの場合はインスタンスに接続せずとも、ダッシュボードから接続情報を確認できますね。SQL Databaseも今後そのように変更されるかもしれません。